# How to see if it is a click or a select (right mouse click) on a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a ListView and I want to do the following:

- when you make a normal click I want to get the event but the list should not be changed and the item should not be selected
- when I select a item (on a non touchscreen device this is the right mouse button) I want to select the item and get a event

but how to catch these two different events in a `ListView` with C#?

I tried: `listView1_RightTapped` but this does not react when I click on a Item just on the empty `ListView`

I also tired `listView1_SelectionChanged` this sould be the first problem, but the item also get selected (e.g. with a other background) which I dont want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SelectionChanged` for selection and `ItemClick` for a click (with `IsItemClickEnabled="True"`).